# Manipulate DOM from directive after data is bound

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

My goal is to create a directive that arranges a set of varied height divs into a pattern that eliminates whitespace between them. Like how Pinterest tessellates divs into a mosaic:

[image: Pinterest screenshot]

My approach to this was:

1. Create a directive that will wrap a set of divs to tessellate.

   ```
   <tessellate columns="6">
       <div ng-repeat="item in items" class="thumbnail">
           {{item.name}}
       </div>
   </tessellate>
   ```
2. Use a directive template to set up the columns first. (tessellateTemplate.html)

   ```
   <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-sm-{{12/columns}}" ng-repeat="i in numberToArray(columns) track by $index"></div>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```
3. Use the directive to grab the divs *after the data has been bound to them* and, one-by-one, add them to the column with the shortest height.

   ```
   app.directive('tessellate', function () {
       return {
           restrict: 'E',
           scope: {
               columns: '='
           },
           controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
               // Ensure number of columns is divisible by 12.
               if (isNaN($scope.columns) || 12 % $scope.columns != 0) {
                   $scope.columns = 6;
               }

               $scope.numberToArray = function (num) {
                   return new Array(num);
               };
           }],

           // Get child divs and add to template here.
           // Should I use compile or link??

           templateUrl: "/app/directives/templates/tessellateTemplate.html"
       };
   });
   ```

Seems simple enough, right? The problem I keep running into is that I can't figure out how to get the divs *after* data has been bound to them. This is important because the real height of the divs is needed to decide which column it should go in.

**Is there a way to manipulate the DOM in the directive *after* data is bound?**

Comment: have you tried ng-init on div ?

Comment: No, I've never used ng-init. I'll have to research that

Comment: try this http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit in place of expression you can pass function too and handle it in scope

Comment: So I'm guessing I'd have to use transclusion then?

Comment: Wait, doesn't ng-init, by design, run _before_ ng-repeat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, the only way I could figure this out was to use $timeout. I'm not a fan of it, but it works. If anyone has a better way, please post an answer. :)

I modified my directive template (tessellateTemplate.html) to transclude the divs:

```
<div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-{{12/columns}}" ng-repeat="i in numberToArray(columns) track by $index"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-transclude></div>
</div>
```

Then I modified my directive to have `transclude: true` and also do the tessellating in a $timeout (please don't laugh at my chained method calls, it's been a while since I've had to use JQuery :P):

```
app.directive('tessellate', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            columns: '='
        },
        controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            // Ensure number of columns is divisible by 12.
            if (isNaN($scope.columns) || 12 % $scope.columns != 0) {
                $scope.columns = 6;
            }

            $scope.numberToArray = function (num) {
                return new Array(num);
            };

            $scope.getShortestColumn = function () {
                var cols = $element.children().first().children().first().children();
                var shortCol = null;
                angular.forEach(cols, function (col) {
                    col = angular.element(col);
                    if (shortCol == null || col.height() < shortCol.height()) {
                        shortCol = col;
                    }
                });
                return shortCol;
            };

            $timeout(function () {
                var divs = $element.children().first().next().children();
                for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
                    $scope.getShortestColumn().append(divs[i]);
                }
            }, 0);
        }],
        templateUrl: "/app/directives/templates/tessellateTemplate.html"
    };
});
```

Usage remains the same:

```
<tessellate columns="6">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        {{item.name}}
    </div>
</tessellate>
```